# Redirect after HTML-Google Form submit

Tags: javascript, html, google-forms

From HTML I am picking value and submitting that into google Forms on submit button. I want to redirect the page after successful submit. Below is the code for reference.I tried using onload but that is not wokring.

```html
<html>
<!-- subscribe -->
<section class="subscribe" id="subscribe">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-5 d-flex subscribe-left p-sm-5 py-4">
    <div class="image mr-3">
     <img src="images/mail.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
     <h3>Subscribe To Our Newsletter</h3>
    </div>
   </div>
   **<script type="text/javascript">var submitted=flase;</script>
   
   <iframe name="hidden_iframe" id="hidden_iframe" style="display:none; "onload=if(submitted)window.location='http://ourpcgeek.com'">**
   
   </iframe>
   <div class="col-lg-7 subscribe-right p-sm-5 py-3">
    <form id="subscribe-form" action="https://docs.google.com/forms" method="post" target="hidden_iframe" >
     <input type="email" name="emailAddress" placeholder="Enter your email here" required="emailAddress">
     <button class="btn1" /><span class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
    </form>
    <p>we never share your email with anyone else</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
<!-- //subscribe -->

</html>
```

Comment: Please update the code it does not run :-)

Comment: @thex Please check now.